# No me funciona anidar variables dentro de cadenas

Tags: php

Aquí mi código:

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli("localhost","root","","usuarios");
$limite = $_POST['cantidad'];
for ($i=0; $i<$limite; $i++) { 
    $sql->query("INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre,apellido,usuario,clave) VALUES ('$_REQUEST[nombre$i]','$_REQUEST[apellido$i]','$_REQUEST[usuario$i]','$_REQUEST[clave$i]') ") or die($mysql->error);
}
$sql->close();
echo "Valores agregados correctamente";
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$i' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ']' in AJAX/procesar.php on line 5

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in AJAX/procesar.php on line 5

:c otra idea? igual se agradece el intento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

- No estás escapando correctamente las variables del interior de las comillas dobles (el problema que te trae aquí). Debes consultar las [sintaxis simple y compleja del entrecomillado doble](https://www.php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double) para entender cómo hacerlo correctamente (ver final de mi respuesta).
- Tu código sufre [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) debido a la forma en la que concatenas el contenido de variables que entrega el usuario al script al código SQL (para mí, es el problema más grave).

La solución más sencilla a ambos problemas podría ser, haciendo uso de [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli.real-escape-string) para solventar el correcto escapado de cadenas en la consulta SQL, la siguiente:

```
<?php
$sql = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "usuarios");
for ($i = 0; $i < min(intval($_POST['cantidad']), 100); $i++) { 
    $sql->query("
      INSERT INTO usuarios (
        nombre,
        apellido,
        usuario,
        clave
      ) VALUES (
        '" . $sql->real_escape_string($_REQUEST["nombre$i"]) ."',
        '" . $sql->real_escape_string($_REQUEST["apellido$i"]) ."',
        '" . $sql->real_escape_string($_REQUEST["usuario$i"]) ."',
        '" . $sql->real_escape_string($_REQUEST["clave$i"]) ."'
      )
    ") or die($mysql->error);
}
$sql->close();
echo "Valores agregados correctamente";
```

Además, como `$_POST['cantidad']` también está fuera de tu control, quizá deberías plantearte limitar el número que puede contener para evitar [ataques de denegación de servicio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_denegaci%C3%B3n_de_servicio). He usado la función [`min()`](https://php.net/min) para limitar a `100` el número máximo de iteraciones.

---

En cuanto al uso de la sintaxis [simple](https://www.php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing.simple) o [compleja](https://www.php.net/language.types.string#language.types.string.parsing.complex) en las cadenas con comillas dobles, aquí tienes varios ejemplos de uso:

- `"${_REQUEST['viajero' . $i]}"` (simple)
- `"{$_REQUEST['viajero' . $i]}"` (compleja)
- `"${_REQUEST["viajero$i"]}"` (simple)
- `"{$_REQUEST["viajero$i"]}"` (compleja)

Aún así insisto en que no concatenes el contenido de variables fuera de tu control (como las de `$_REQUEST`) a una consulta SQL. Siempre debes usar la función de escapado de o hacer uso de [consultas/sentencias preparadas](https://php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias señor, además de solucionarme el problema me ayudaste en otros campos que claramente debo mejorar, gracias!

Comment: Un placer haber sido de ayuda 